# How to rotate UILabel as a whole

Tags: swift, xcode

I have written a code which should turn UILabel by Z axis and then by Y axis to simulate perspective. Here is the sample code:

```
var t: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, 270 * CGFloat.pi / 180, 0, 0, 1) // rotate by z axis
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, -50 * CGFloat.pi / 180, 0, 1, 0) // rotate by y axis
t.m34 = 1.0 / -500
logLabel.transform3D = t // implement sequence of rotations to label
contentView.addSubview(logLabel)
```

It rotates by Z axis correctly, but it does not rotate by Y axis. The second rotation makes the label to look narrow. How to simulate perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You must set the `m34` **before** you set the rotation.

```
var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 65 * CGFloat.pi / 180, 1, 0, 0)
        
label.layer.transform = transform
```

Result:

[image: 3d transformed label, star wars style]

---

Old answer:

You might want to change the `m34`

```
t.m34 = 1.0 / -500
```

This sets how "far" the label is... more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596326/14351818)

Comment: I added the code but it wasn't the effect expected. It seems like as the UILabel is 2d, and I try to emulate it on 3d space. It is narrower but I want beginning of the text to be smaller and the end to be bigger, i.e. trapezoid not rectangle :)

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you found a solution yet? Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Just realized you need to set `m34` *before* you set the rotation. Edited my answer.

Comment: I wonder why the sequence of rotations is so important.