# How to achieve a 3D effect with UIView - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to achieve the effect same as the attached image. How can I place a view at certain angle? I tried using `UIBezierPath` with no success.

[image: Tilted View]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CATransform3DRotate` alongside the `m34` property, which manages depth. Just make sure you [set `m34` **before** the rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64106839/14351818).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 15 * .pi / 180, 1, 0, 0)
         
    cardView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cardView.layer.transform = transform
}
```

Result:

[image: Blue card with perspective, looks like it's tilting forwards (bottom edge is wider than top edge)]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CATransform3DConcat` [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1436554-catransform3dconcat)

```
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(view.layer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi/4, .zero, .zero, .zero))
```

Comment: I think you meant `view.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(view.layer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi/4, .zero, .zero, .zero))` (`view.transform` is a CGAffineTransform, while `view.layer.transform` is a CATransform3D).